# Phoenix framework - node modules installation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

There was a question about installing modules using node js (npm). For example, I install particlesJS using npm.

> npm i particlesjs

Installation completed successfully.

I import particlesJS in app.js file

```
import particlesjs from "particlesjs"
```

But in the console I see an error

> particlesJS is not defined

I'm still not good at working with npm and phoenix and I’d really like to figure out how to connect the modules correctly.

P.S
For work with jQuery I added the lines to app.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = $
window.$ = $
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an typo issue

from call function

> particlesJS

and import function as

> particlesjs

Answer (score 0):

That might be because the `package.json` on Phoenix projects are placed inside the `assets/` subfolder. So when you're running `npm i particlesjs` at the root directory, it doesn't properly update your package.json and such.

Try using `cd assets && npm i particlesjs`.

Also there's another package called `particles.js` (with the dot separation). Maybe this is the one you're searching for? Since [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/particle.js) shows something similar to your piece of code.

Also, you might have a typo since you're importing all lowercase "particlejs" and the error message shows "particleJS"

Hope this helps :)